# How to move the comment form to the top?

Tags: theming, 8, comments

Per default in Drupal 8 the comment form is rendered below the comments. In Drupal 7 you could move the comment form from the bottom to the top by modifying the comment-wrapper.tpl.php.

Is there also a way in Drupal 8 to get this functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can in **[field--comment.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!comment!templates!field--comment.html.twig/8.2.x)**

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme override for comment fields.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - attributes: HTML attributes for the containing element.
 * - label_hidden: Whether to show the field label or not.
 * - title_attributes: HTML attributes for the title.
 * - label: The label for the field.
 * - title_prefix: Additional output populated by modules, intended to be
 *   displayed in front of the main title tag that appears in the template.
 * - title_suffix: Additional title output populated by modules, intended to
 *   be displayed after the main title tag that appears in the template.
 * - comments: List of comments rendered through comment.html.twig.
 * - content_attributes: HTML attributes for the form title.
 * - comment_form: The 'Add new comment' form.
 * - comment_display_mode: Is the comments are threaded.
 * - comment_type: The comment type bundle ID for the comment field.
 * - entity_type: The entity type to which the field belongs.
 * - field_name: The name of the field.
 * - field_type: The type of the field.
 * - label_display: The display settings for the label.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_field()
 * @see comment_preprocess_field()
 */
#}
<section{{ attributes }}>
  {% if comments and not label_hidden %}
    {{ title_prefix }}
    <h2{{ title_attributes }}>{{ label }}</h2>
    {{ title_suffix }}
  {% endif %}

  {{ comments }}

  {% if comment_form %}
    <h2{{ content_attributes }}>{{ 'Add new comment'|t }}</h2>
    {{ comment_form }}
  {% endif %}

</section>
```

So copy the above code and go to `/themes/YOURTHEME/templates` folder and create field--comment.html.twig and now paste code.

Now, all you gotta do is just move

```
 {% if comment_form %}
    <h2{{ content_attributes }}>{{ 'Add new comment'|t }}</h2>
    {{ comment_form }}
  {% endif %}
```

and place it above the `{{ comments }}` line

Flush/Clear the cache to see changes.

Answer (score 1):

For change the placement of comment form in drupal 8, you can work on the field--comment.html.twig file. Put this file to your theme. 
[image]